# Disable Tier Price in Backend Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, price, backend, tierprice

Does anyone know a way to not display the tier price in the backend of Magento @product page?

Due to the large list of Tier pice loading a product takes a long time, in de backbend.

when i try to remove the attribute from the Management attributes sets default I get a message I can not remove it.

Comment: Do you want to delete tier prices for all the products?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tier_price` is system attribute given by default Magento which can not be deleted. You can manage it by another way.

1. login in to your database phpmyadmin
2. Go to your Magento installation database
3. Find eav_attribute table
4. Find the entry with attribute code with tier_price
5. Edit the row and change is_user_defined from 0 to 1.

Now go to `Admin -> Catalog -> Attribute -> Manage Attribute Set -> Select Attribute Set` and remove tier_price from price group and it will be remove from your product in admin.

Answer (score -2):

Goto

```
frontend/default/yourtheme/tempalte/catalog/product/view.phtml
```

Then comment below mentioned line

```
echo $this->getTierPriceHtml()
```

Comment: This will disable the tier prices in the Magento admin section.